# Add statistics in complex grouped barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, anova, p-value

I would like to add statistics to my plot, but I do not know how to do it.
For each concentration reported in the x-axis, I have three different groups: Control, SNCB and SNCA (in this exact order). I would like to add some statistics and some stars. In particular, I would like to show in each concentration reported on the x-axis, the last bar (SNCA) is significantly different compared to the first (CTRL) and the second (SNCB) bar.

This is my dataset:

```
| concentrations samples   N    value       sd         se        ci
1           SCgal    CTRL 324 5.328536 3.618416 0.20102310 0.3954799
2           SCgal    SNCB 324 5.088752 3.290355 0.18279752 0.3596241
3           SCgal    SNCA 324 2.140706 1.639086 0.09106033 0.1791462
4             5uM    CTRL 324 4.973646 3.263561 0.18130893 0.3566955
5             5uM    SNCB 324 4.071736 2.711828 0.15065714 0.2963931
6             5uM    SNCA 324 1.360853 1.034978 0.05749877 0.1131194
7            10uM    CTRL 324 4.793505 3.363303 0.18685016 0.3675970
8            10uM    SNCB 324 5.238060 3.341916 0.18566201 0.3652595
9            10uM    SNCA 324 1.457595 1.073308 0.05962823 0.1173087
10           15uM    CTRL 324 4.931072 3.385016 0.18805644 0.3699701
11           15uM    SNCB 324 5.599540 3.497638 0.19431325 0.3822794
12           15uM    SNCA 324 1.724697 1.178986 0.06549924 0.1288590
13           20uM    CTRL 324 4.956412 3.387070 0.18817056 0.3701946
14           20uM    SNCB 324 5.535659 3.457279 0.19207107 0.3778683
15           20uM    SNCA 324 1.799426 1.207254 0.06706967 0.1319486
16           30uM    CTRL 324 5.013223 3.405159 0.18917550 0.3721717
17           30uM    SNCB 324 5.431113 3.400815 0.18893415 0.3716969
```

[image]

I tried different paths: `geom_signif()` and `stat_compare_means()`, but nothing work :(

Here is the code of my plot with geom_signif()

```
barre <-ggplot(tgallto2, aes(x = factor(concentrations,levels = level_order), y = value, group = samples)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue')) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge2", color="black", show.legend = FALSE, fill = "blue") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se), position = "dodge2", width=0.90, fill = "black",show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("SNCB", "CTRL")),
              map_signif_level = TRUE,
              annotations = c("***")) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=15,vjust = +2),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=15,vjust = -.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=15, color = "#000000"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, color = "#000000"))
barre + ylim(0,8) + ylab( "OD600 nm") + xlab("Thiamine concentrations uM") + ggtitle("Thiamine effect")
```

Here is the code of my plot with stat_compare_means()

```
my_comparison <- list(c("SNCB", "CTRL"), c("SNCA", "CTRL"), c("SNCA", "SNCB"))
barre <-ggplot(tgallto2, aes(x = factor(concentrations,levels = level_order), y = value, group = samples)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue')) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge2", color="black", show.legend = FALSE, fill = "blue") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se), position = "dodge2", width=0.90, fill = "black",show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=15,vjust = +2),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=15,vjust = -.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=15, color = "#000000"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, color = "#000000"))
barre + ylim(0,8) + ylab( "OD600 nm") + xlab("Thiamine concentrations uM") + ggtitle("Thiamine effect")
barre + stat_compare_means(aes(group=concentrations), label = "p.signif", method = "t.test",
```

Do you know how to fix this problem? And if I should change statistics considering I am compared three groups for each conditions?

Comment: It looks like you've got exactly one value for each concentration~samples. You can't do a t-test on one observation. If these are the averages by group, you need to go back to the original data in order to compare the means. When you do, then you can tackle how to add the stats. If you have the `p` values, you can use `geom_signif` with `manual = T` or use the `text` argument in `ggplot`.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg